# Unit test a dynamically populating user control in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, moq, mvp

I have a WinForms project with MVP pattern (passive view) implemented.

I think that I have a problem with the pattern when it comes to a user control, which I figured out during unit testing

I have a user control that I put on my form as a result of an event fired in my view. That user control adds a certain amount of labels, textboxes, etc. to itsself based on a number it gets from the view. Finally, it tells the view to add the user control to the view.

I want to unit test the logic in this class, since that is what I think is most important to test. I just do not know how to do this, since there is both logic and form controls in this class. I am currently using Moq for creating my unit tests.

I would normally create a Mock object to represent the view and then test the implementation of the methods in the object to be tested in isolation. However, since I create controls in this class, I don't think I can test this like this (without including the .Forms library that is).

I hope someone knows a solution.

**EDIT:** I have been trying to separate my logic from the control manipulation, but I am struggling with a function from a different user control I have posted below the original user control code. Since I loop through a list of controls, I dont know how to separate this into just logic and just control handling.

**User control code**

```
public partial class DetailScreenUserControl : UserControl
{
    // Private members.
    private readonly IDetailScreenView _view;
    private List<ComboBox> maturityInput = new List<ComboBox>();
    private List<ComboBox> complianceInput = new List<ComboBox>();

    // Public members.
    public List<string> MaturityInput
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < maturityInput.Count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(maturityInput[i].Text);
            }
            return list;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maturityInput.Count; i++)
            {
                maturityInput[i].DataSource = new List<string>(value);
            }
        }
    }
    public List<string> ComplianceInput
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < complianceInput.Count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(complianceInput[i].Text);
            }
            return list;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < complianceInput.Count; i++)
            {
                complianceInput[i].DataSource = new List<string>(value);
            }
        }
    }

    // Initialize user control with IDetailScreenView. Subscribe to necessary events.
    public DetailScreenUserControl(IDetailScreenView view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _view = view;
        _view.InitializingUserControl += InitializeUserControl;
    }

    // Initializes the user control for the detail screen.
    public void InitializeUserControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> qStandards = _view.SelectedQuestionStandards;
        Controls.Clear();
        maturityInput.Clear();
        complianceInput.Clear();

        int inputSeparation = Height / 2;
        int spacing = Width / 20;

        Size = new Size(_view.RightUserControlBoundary - Location.X, Size.Height);

        for (int  i = 0; i < qStandards.Count; i++)
        {
            Panel inputPanel = new Panel();
            inputPanel.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            inputPanel.Location = new Point(0, i * inputSeparation);
            inputPanel.Size = new Size(Width - spacing, inputSeparation);
            Controls.Add(inputPanel);

            Label qs_label = new Label();
            qs_label.AutoSize = true;
            qs_label.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            qs_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold);
            qs_label.AutoSize = true;
            qs_label.Text = qStandards[i].ToString();
            inputPanel.Controls.Add(qs_label);

            Label m_label = new Label();
            m_label.AutoSize = true;
            m_label.Location = new Point(0, qs_label.Bounds.Bottom + qs_label.Height / 2);
            m_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular);
            m_label.Text = "Maturity standard";
            inputPanel.Controls.Add(m_label);

            Label c_label = new Label();
            c_label.AutoSize = true;
            c_label.Location = new Point(0, m_label.Bounds.Bottom + qs_label.Height / 2);
            c_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular);
            c_label.Text = "Compliance standard";
            inputPanel.Controls.Add(c_label);

            ComboBox m_input = new ComboBox();
            m_input.AutoSize = true;
            m_input.Location = new Point(c_label.Bounds.Right + 2 * spacing, m_label.Bounds.Top);
            m_input.Font = new Font("Arial", 10F, FontStyle.Regular);
            m_input.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            m_input.Size = new Size(inputPanel.Size.Width - m_input.Bounds.Left, spacing);
            maturityInput.Add(m_input);
            inputPanel.Controls.Add(m_input);

            ComboBox c_input = new ComboBox();
            c_input.AutoSize = true;
            c_input.Location = new Point(c_label.Bounds.Right + 2 * spacing, c_label.Bounds.Top);
            c_input.Font = new Font("Arial", 10F, FontStyle.Regular);
            c_input.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            c_input.Size = new Size(inputPanel.Size.Width - c_input.Bounds.Left, spacing);
            complianceInput.Add(c_input);
            inputPanel.Controls.Add(c_input);

        }

        if(qStandards.Count != 0)
        {
            saveAssessmentButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            Controls.Add(saveAssessmentButton);
            saveAssessmentButton.Location = new Point(this.Size.Width - saveAssessmentButton.Width - spacing, qStandards.Count * inputSeparation);
        }

        _view.AddUserControl();
    }

    // Tells the view to save the assessment.
    private void saveAssessmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _view.SaveAssessmentButtonClicked();
    }
}
```

**Other user control function**('answers' is the list of controls)

```
public void SaveResults()
{
    results = new List<string>();
    int questionNr = 0;

    for (int p = 0; p < questions.Count; p++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < questions[p].Count; i++)
        {
            bool unanswered = true;

            results.Add(questions[p][i]);

            for (int j = 1; j <= maturityAnswers[p].Count; j++)
            {
                var radioButton = (RadioButton)answers[questionNr][j];
                if (radioButton.Checked)
                {
                    results.Add(answers[questionNr][j].Text);
                    unanswered = false;
                }
            }
            if (unanswered == true)
            {
                results.Add("");
            }
            unanswered = true;

            for (int j = maturityAnswers[p].Count + 1; j <= (maturityAnswers[p].Count + complianceAnswers[p].Count); j++)
            {
                var radioButton = (RadioButton)answers[questionNr][j];
                if (radioButton.Checked)
                {
                    results.Add(answers[questionNr][j].Text);
                    unanswered = false;
                }
            }
            if (unanswered == true)
            {
                results.Add("");
            }

            results.Add(answers[questionNr][0].Text.Replace("'", "''"));

            questionNr++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to unit test the logic in this class, since that is what I
>   think is most important to test. I just do not know how to do this,
>   **since there is both logic and form controls in this class**

So separate them to different classes and test the class which contains only logic

Comment: Haha yea that seems like the logical thing to do, doesn't it ;p. It's just that this will be pretty difficult since the control manipulation and the logic is so intertwined, but I'll give it a go. I just had this idea in my head that a User Control could contain its own logic without a separate class, but I guess that was a misunderstanding on my behalf.